# How to redirect "#q" with "?q" in url

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, redirect

I need to update a url that at the moment is:

www.examplesite.com/#q=test

to

www.examplesite.com/?q=test

I've try various methods with .htaccess and javascript without success.

Users comes into #q and I need to redirect to ?q

Thanks

Comment: You can't do this because the server doesn't recognize anything after the # sign. You can add it in the substitution part of the rewriterule but not the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the HTML `meta` element for redirection?

```
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://google.com/?q=hi" />
</head>
</html>
```

If you would rather use Javascript, you can use: 
`location.href = "http://www.google.com/?q=hi";`

Comment: Hey, thank you for you answer. The problem is that i need to refresh the page by keep the variable in q parameter. So this unfortunately  can't help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you, but if you want to use JS to get the current hashtag value, you can use `window.location.hash`